# How to merge queryset into a single result without any repetation?

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

My Model:

```
class GroupBase(models.Model):
    """
    Predefined base group name
    """
    YesNo = (
        ('Yes', 'Yes'),
        ('No', 'No')
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    parent = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    is_revenue = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=YesNo, default='No')
    affects_trading = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=YesNo, default='No')
    is_debit = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=YesNo, default='No')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class LedgerGroup(models.Model):
    """
    Ledger Group Master
    """

    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    group_base = models.ForeignKey(GroupBase, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='base_group', default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name

class LedgerMaster(models.Model):
    """
    Ledger Master
    """
    ledger_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)  # unique together with company using meta
    ledger_group = models.ForeignKey(LedgerGroup, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='group_ledger')
    closing_balance = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ledger_name
```

I have the following queries:

```
group_debit_positive = GroupBase.objects.filter(base_group__group_ledger__company=company,is_debit__exact='Yes',base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance__gt=0).annotate(
        total_debit_positive=Coalesce(Sum('base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance'), Value(0)),
        total_debit_negative=Sum(0,output_field=FloatField()),
        total_credit_positive=Sum(0,output_field=FloatField()),
        total_credit_negative=Sum(0,output_field=FloatField()))

group_debit_negative = GroupBase.objects.filter(base_group__group_ledger__company=company,is_debit__exact='Yes',base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance__lt=0).annotate(
        total_debit_positive=Sum(0,output_field=FloatField()),
        total_debit_negative=Coalesce(Sum('base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance'), Value(0)),
        total_credit_positive=Sum(0,output_field=FloatField()),
        total_credit_negative=Sum(0,output_field=FloatField()))

group_credit_positive = GroupBase.objects.filter(base_group__group_ledger__company=company,is_debit__exact='No',base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance__gt=0).annotate(
        total_debit_positive=Sum(0,output_field=FloatField()),
        total_debit_negative=Sum(0,output_field=FloatField()),
        total_credit_positive=Coalesce(Sum('base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance'), Value(0)),
        total_credit_negative=Sum(0,output_field=FloatField()))

group_credit_negative = GroupBase.objects.filter(base_group__group_ledger__company=company,is_debit__exact='No',base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance__lt=0).annotate(
        total_debit_positive=Sum(0,output_field=FloatField()),
        total_debit_negative=Sum(0,output_field=FloatField()),
        total_credit_positive=Sum(0,output_field=FloatField()),
        total_credit_negative=Coalesce(Sum('base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance'), Value(0)))
```

I have performed union of all the queries:

```
final_set = group_debit_positive.union(group_debit_negative,group_credit_positive,group_credit_negative)
```

I want to get a single result rather then getting repetation in my union queryset.

For example:

whenever I am trying to print the resulted queryset

```
for g in final_set:
        print(g.name,'-',g.total_credit_positive,'-',g.total_credit_negative)
```

I am getting results like this:

```
Sundry Creditors - 0.0 - -213075
Purchase Accounts - 0.0 - 0.0
Sundry Creditors - 95751.72 - 0.
Sales Accounts - 844100.0 - 0.0
Sales Accounts - 0.0 - -14000.0
```

As you can see `Sales Account` is repeated twice.

I want something like the following:

```
Sundry Creditors - 0.0 - -213075
Purchase Accounts - 0.0 - 0.0
Sundry Creditors - 95751.72 - 0.
Sales Accounts - 844100.0 - -14000.0
```

How to stop the repetition of results and make it into a single result.

Any idea anyone how to perform this?

**EDIT**

I further tried using "|" to merge the queryset, it is merging successfully without repetation but it is adding the result with the same name.

I have done the following:

```
final_queryset = group_debit_positive | group_debit_negative | group_credit_positive | group_credit_negative
```

The result is coming out like this:

```
Sundry Creditors - -213075 - 0.0
Purchase Accounts - 0.0 - 0.0
Sundry Creditors - 95751.72 - 0.
Sales Accounts - 830100 - 0.0
```

Its adding the result
like the result `Sales Accounts` is becoming `830100(844100.0 + (-14000.0)`.

Can anyone help me to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Thank you

Comment: Can you update to include the related models to `GroupBase`?

Comment: It's worth noting that you *don't* need to use `Value(0)`, since int, float, and bool types are wrapped in `Value` impllicitly.  You only need to use it when working with string arguments.  See the docs on [Value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions) for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `filter` argument for `Sum` with a different `Q` object for each annotation instead. Also use the `values` method of the queryset to group the output by the `name` field, so there won't be separate entries of the same name in the output:

```
final_set = GroupBase.objects.filter(
    base_group__group_ledger__company=company).values('name').annotate(
    total_debit_positive=Sum('base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance', output_field=FloatField(),
        filter=Q(is_debit__exact='Yes', base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance__gt=0)),
    total_debit_negative=Sum('base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance', output_field=FloatField(),
        filter=Q(is_debit__exact='Yes', base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance__lt=0)),
    total_credit_positive=Sum('base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance', output_field=FloatField(),
        filter=Q(is_debit__exact='No', base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance__gt=0)),
    total_credit_negative=Sum('base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance', output_field=FloatField(),
        filter=Q(is_debit__exact='No', base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance__lt=0))
)
for g in final_set:
    print(
        g['name'], g['total_debit_positive'], g['total_debiit_negative'],
        g['total_credit_positive'], g['total_credit_negative'], sep=' - '
    )
```

Comment: Its throwing me this error `Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field`

Comment: I see. I missed adding the `output_field` parameter for `Sum`. It's now fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Can you try constructing one queryset using `Case` and `When` instead of union like:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When

final_set = GroupBase.objects.filter(base_group__group_ledger__company=company).annotate(
    total_debit_positive=Case(
        When(is_debit__exact='Yes', base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance__gt=0, then=Coalesce(Sum('base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance'), Value(0))),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=FloatField()
    ),
    total_debit_negative=Case(
        When(is_debit__exact='Yes', base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance__lt=0, then=Coalesce(Sum('base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance'), Value(0))),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=FloatField()
    ),
    total_credit_positive=Case(
        When(is_debit__exact='No', base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance__gt=0, then=Coalesce(Sum('base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance'), Value(0))),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=FloatField()
    ),
    total_credit_negative=Case(
        When(is_debit__exact='No', base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance__lt=0, then=Coalesce(Sum('base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance'), Value(0))),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=FloatField()
    )
```

Comment: It is also causing repetation

Comment: Is it working if you add [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)?

Comment: Nope...The name is repetated according to condition

Comment: Can you elaborate more on that? What do you mean by repeated? Can you provide an example of data and result? I'm pretty sure that this example can be fixed if there is anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

**.annotate()**

You have to perform query on `LedgerMaster` model to get the preferred results to avoid repetition. use `Case, When` to get different values based on inline filter

```
from django.db.models import Case, When

final_set = LedgerMaster.objects.filter(
    company=company
).values('ledger_group__group_base__name').annotate(
    total_debit_positive=Case(
        When(ledger_group__group_base__name__is_debit__exact='Yes', closing_balance__gt=0,
             then=Coalesce(Sum('base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance'), Value(0))),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=FloatField()
    ),
    total_debit_negative=Case(
        When(ledger_group__group_base__name__is_debit__exact='Yes', closing_balance__lt=0,
             then=Coalesce(Sum('base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance'), Value(0))),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=FloatField()
    ),
    total_credit_positive=Case(
        When(ledger_group__group_base__name__is_debit__exact='No', closing_balance__gt=0,
             then=Coalesce(Sum('base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance'), Value(0))),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=FloatField()
    ),
    total_credit_negative=Case(
        When(ledger_group__group_base__name__is_debit__exact='No', closing_balance__lt=0,
             then=Coalesce(Sum('base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance'), Value(0))),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=FloatField()
    ),
).order_by()
```

output data will be like:

```
[
    {
        'ledger_group__group_base__name': <group_base_nameA>,
        'total_debit_positive': <amount>,
        'total_debit_negative': <amount>,
        'total_credit_positive': <amount>,
        'total_credit_negative': <amount>,
    },
    {
        'ledger_group__group_base__name': <group_base_nameB>,
        'total_debit_positive': <amount>,
        'total_debit_negative': <amount>,
        'total_credit_positive': <amount>,
        'total_credit_negative': <amount>,
    },
    ....
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much everyone, Finally I got the solution to my Question, and thought of posting it for others reference.

These are my queries:

```
    group_debit_positive = GroupBase.objects.filter(base_group__group_ledger__company=company, is_debit__exact='Yes', base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance__gt=0).annotate(
        total_debit_positive_opening=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_debit_negative_opening=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_credit_positive_opening=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_credit_negative_opening=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_debit_positive=Coalesce(
            Sum('base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance'), Value(0)),
        total_debit_negative=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_credit_positive=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_credit_negative=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField())).exclude(name__exact='Primary').exclude(name__exact='Current Assets').values(
            'name',
            'total_debit_positive',
            'total_debit_negative',
            'total_credit_positive',
            'total_credit_negative')

    group_debit_negative = GroupBase.objects.filter(base_group__group_ledger__company=company, is_debit__exact='Yes', base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance__lt=0).annotate(
        total_debit_positive_opening=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_debit_negative_opening=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_credit_positive_opening=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_credit_negative_opening=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_debit_positive=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_debit_negative=Coalesce(
            Sum('base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance'), Value(0)),
        total_credit_positive=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_credit_negative=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField())).exclude(name__exact='Primary').exclude(name__exact='Current Assets').values(
            'name',
            'total_debit_positive',
            'total_debit_negative',
            'total_credit_positive',
            'total_credit_negative')

    group_credit_positive = GroupBase.objects.filter(base_group__group_ledger__company=company, is_debit__exact='No', base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance__gt=0).annotate(
        total_debit_positive_opening=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_debit_negative_opening=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_credit_positive_opening=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_credit_negative_opening=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_debit_positive=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_debit_negative=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_credit_positive=Coalesce(
            Sum('base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance'), Value(0)),
        total_credit_negative=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField())).exclude(name__exact='Primary').exclude(name__exact='Current Assets').values(
            'name',
            'total_debit_positive',
            'total_debit_negative',
            'total_credit_positive',
            'total_credit_negative')

    group_credit_negative = GroupBase.objects.filter(base_group__group_ledger__company=company, is_debit__exact='No', base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance__lt=0).annotate(
        total_debit_positive_opening=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_debit_negative_opening=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_credit_positive_opening=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_credit_negative_opening=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_debit_positive=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_debit_negative=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_credit_positive=Sum(0, output_field=FloatField()),
        total_credit_negative=Coalesce(Sum('base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance'), Value(0))).exclude(name__exact='Primary').exclude(name__exact='Current Assets').values(
            'name',
            'total_debit_positive',
            'total_debit_negative',
            'total_credit_positive',
            'total_credit_negative')
```

First I return a Queryset containing dictionary.

Then I performed union among the queries, as in my Question

```
final_queryset = group_debit_positive.union(
        group_debit_negative, group_credit_positive, group_credit_negative, all=True).order_by('name')
```

Then I filter the queries Group By their `name` to avoid duplicate result (as annotation/aggregation cannot be performed in union querysets)

```
grouped_group_name = itertools.groupby(
        final_queryset, key=lambda x: (x['name']))
```

Then,

```
result = []
    for group_key, group_values in grouped_group_name:
        positive_debit = decimal.Decimal(0.0)
        negative_debit = decimal.Decimal(0.0)
        positive_credit = decimal.Decimal(0.0)
        negative_credit = decimal.Decimal(0.0)

        # Storing each value into a variable to render a list later
        for each_group in group_values:
            positive_debit += decimal.Decimal(
                each_group['total_debit_positive'])
            negative_debit += decimal.Decimal(
                each_group['total_debit_negative'])
            positive_credit += decimal.Decimal(
                each_group['total_credit_positive'])
            negative_credit += decimal.Decimal(
                each_group['total_credit_negative'])

        # Making a list of items fetched to render in Django Template
        result.append({
            'group_name': group_key,
            'positive_debit': round(positive_debit, 2),
            'negative_debit': round(negative_debit, 2),
            'positive_credit': round(positive_credit, 2),
            'negative_credit': round(negative_credit, 2),
        })
```

In this way I was able to get the solution to my problem.

I know Its a bit lengthy process.

Thank you every one for the help..

Comment: Using `itertools.groupby` to remove duplicates on the client side is rather inefficient. It's best to perform GROUP BY on the server side. Did you try my solution of using the `values` method after my fix?

Comment: Yeah I had tried your solution,its later throwing me this error `function sum() does not exist`...I appreciate your solution as it was simple and easy to understand, if it works without errors I will definitely use it.

Comment: Ahh sorry I missed the most important parameter for `Sum`--the field needed to sum, namely `'base_group__group_ledger__closing_balance'`. Can you try my new fix again? It's easy to miss things when I don't have your database to test the code with. :-)

Answer (score -2):

Is there a `order_by` in the `class Meta` of your `GroupBase` model?

That can cause irregularities [0] when aggregating/annotating.  Try adding an empty `.order_by()` to your queries and see if that solves the problem.

[0] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by)

Comment: No I have not introduced `class Meta` in `GroupBase` model

Comment: Hmm, can you add the code for your `GroupBase` model to the question?

Comment: Thanks, did you try adding the empty `.order_by()` to your `group_credit_negative = ...`?